# jquery-url in nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to port some js code that's using jquery-url into nodejs.

jquery-url is used to get the hostname of a given URL in this way:

```
var host = $.url(url).attr('host');
```

My question is, is there a npm package of jquery-url? if not, what already existing package has this functionality?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node.js already has this build in. See [node Documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html).

For Example:

```
var url = require("url");
var host = url.parse('http://user:pass@host.com:8080/p/a/t/h?query=string#hash').host;
console.log(host);
```